# Matlab imrect in infinite loop

Tags: matlab, user-interface, radio-button, infinite-loop

I have a Matlab UI where I want the user to **input several areas using `imrect`** as soon as a radiobutton is selected.
It is unknown how many areas will be selected so the selection needs to be in an infinite loop.
As soon as **another radiobutton is selected, the `imrect` input should stop**, which I cannot get to work.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
function mwe
ax = axes('Position', [0 0 1 1]);
bg = uibuttongroup('Position',[0 0 .15 1], 'SelectionChangedFcn',{@bselection, ax});
r1 = uicontrol(bg, 'Style','radiobutton', 'String','Option 1', 'Position',[10 250 100 30]);
r2 = uicontrol(bg, 'Style','radiobutton', 'String','Option 2', 'Position',[10 225 100 30], 'Value',1);

function bselection(source, event, ax)
  switch event.NewValue.String
    case 'Option 1'
      while true
        h = imrect(ax);
        % do stuff
        delete(h);
      end
    case 'Option 2'
      % do not show imrect and do other stuff
  end
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [Interruptible property](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/radiobutton-properties.html) on the button. You can also set `BusyAction` to `cancel`. The help says:

> The interruption occurs at the next point where MATLAB processes the
>   queue, such as when there is a drawnow, uifigure, getframe, waitfor,
>   or pause command.

So if you include a 'pause', it may not stop until the next rectangle has been selected. This is because once you've called `imrect`, it may not know that it has to stop.

However this method may not work if `imrect` blocks the matlab UI from triggering a callback.

An altogether better way is **not** to use an endless loop. You need to tell it when to end by checking --

```
running = true;
while running
  h=imrect(ax)
  % do stuff
  delete(h)
  if (SOMETHING)
      running = false
  end
end
```

What is SOMETHING? We need to check if the button has been deselected.

You could use

```
if r1.Value!=1
  running = false
end
```

Which would check if r1 is not selected, and if so, running becomes false, and the loop stops cycling round.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Your solutions works quite well. I found a short way to check the radiobutton selection by replacing `while true` with `while strcmp(source.SelectedObject.String, 'Option 1')`. The only problem though is that after changing the radiobutton selection, `imrect` will still be executed one last time. To solve this I use a workaround by simulating an escape button press when Option 2 is selected, so in `case 'Option 2'` I have added `robot = java.awt.Robot; robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE); robot.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);`.